# Best way to pass some variable/id through google cloud functions child?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-functions

How to get this running ? Need to pass the itens id in the path to have access to product node, how can I do this ?

```
const itens = db.ref();
const eanRef = itens.child('cart').child('itens/{id}').child('product');
```

Comment: Please, be more clear and provide more code. We can't help with this!

Answer (score 0):

To replace the value of an integer variable `id` to a string `itens/{id}` you can do the following:

```js
var id = 15;

const itens = db.ref();
const eanRef = itens.child('cart').child('itens/'+id.toString()).child('product');
```

Comment: If you have further issues with your code, please add an error stack trace. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
const id = 'id-whatever'
const itens = db.ref();
const eanRef = itens.child('cart').child(`itens/${id}`).child('product');
```